# MVC3+Razor template/guidance with custom membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, custom-membershipprovider

I'm pretty new to MVC and looking for an MVC3/Razor web project template that uses a custom membership provider (or custom authentication whatsoever).

I want the project to contain a SQL database, that has a simple User/Role/UserRole scheme, and the user table contains a UserId, Username and Password fields (preferable encrypted), and some login functionality that works thru it.

Any direct link or guidance on how to do it the short way will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had to do this I started with [Asp.Net MVC Membership Starter Kit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit). Good luck!

Comment: Is this MVC3? The other answer provides something that is not only MVC3 but also EFCodeFirst which I also want very much,  I want to follow the newest technologies possible.

Comment: Sounds like you can merge the both. The starter kit works with a provider, weather that is the default out of the box ones, or a custom EF CodeFirst one it shouldn't matter.

Comment: The project in my answer, it doesn't use Membership.ValidateUser, it directly accesses the context. I want it to be a WCF (RIA?) service, and the Membership.ValidateUser should do it, got me?

Comment: The project in my answer, it doesn't use Membership.ValidateUser, it directly accesses the context. My goal is to create an internal MembershipProvider (that has my custom semantics i.e. login without email or whatever different than the MS membership provider)

Comment: So you want to create your own membership, and possibly role/profile provider? Have you seen [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/Source-Code-for-the-Built_2D00_in-ASP.NET-2.0-Providers-Now-Available-for-Download.aspx). Its the source code for the MS providers and its a pretty good starting point. Did I understand your goal correctly?